# Reflecting LuaBridge classes from Lua scripts

Tags: c++, c, lua, luabridge

Before April 2019, it was possible for a Lua script to reflect the methods and properties of a LuaBridge class using string keys `__parent`, `__class`, `__propget`, and `__propset`. This was an incredibly useful tool for creating test scripts and development tools to maintain a large class framework exported into Lua.

From looking through the release notes of LuaBridge, it seems the string keys were removed for security reasons. But I find myself placing more priority on the ability to reflect classes from scripts than on whether scripts can muck around in the object model. Especially in dev mode.

The [LuaBridge Reference Manual implies](http://vinniefalco.github.io/LuaBridge/Manual.html#s5) there is a way for a C/C++ program to expose the metatables, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it. I am quite new to interfacing between C and Lua (or LuaBridge), so I'm not surprised that I am perplexed. If anyone could share an example of how to do this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one seems to have a good suggestion, I realized I could roll my own reflection of the *names* of properties, methods, and constants. For my purposes I don't really need to execute or access them.

So rather than muck around inside `LuaBridge` I added `__class`, `__propget`, and `__propset` static properties to every class in my framework. These return a table implemented with `std::map` which `LuaBridge` supports. The tables simple have the names as keys and a dummy value.

One caveat I discovered is that you have to add static properties to derived classes when creating the derived class with `deriveClass`. If you try to add them later (using `beginClass`), `LuaBridge` throws an assert.